# is there a way to get reach estimate of a custom audience?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Based from what I know , in facebook , only the saved audience can get the reach estimate in targeting, but in custom audience, we cannot get reach estimate. So is it possible to do that ?, I thought of passing the custom audience id in the targeting specs when trying to get a reach estimate , like e.g

```
targeting_spec = array(
'age_min' => 13,
'age_max' => 25,
'genders' => array(1,2),
'geo_locations' => array(
  'countries' => array(
     'US'
   )
),
'custom_audiences' => array(
   array('id' => $customAudience['id'])
),
```

But this one is wrong, what if I want to get the reach estimate of the same custom audience but with different retention_days ?, I cannot just easily alter the $customAudience array , since the record from facebook won't change at all. And also, the geo location field, How can I change this if the custom audience I am passing don't even have a country data as facebook doesn't allow/nor provide an api input for geo_location.